# Catching focus out event of a datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to catch the focus out event of a datagrid so that everytime, datagrid in edit mode focuses out, I should be able to close out the edit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the LostFocus event to do this.

```
//Short Version
gridview1.LostFocus += (sender, e) => {//Your code to close edit mode};
```

Or normally you would do it as:

```
//Normal long Version
gridview1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(gridview1_LostFocus);
```

some where define your method for event handeling

```
public void gridview1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     //Your code to close edit mode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.celleditending.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't want to let user edit cells values if that

use the dataGridView CellBeginEdit event

```
dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit);
```

and then cancel then edit in event handling

```
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

i hope this help.